# Finding the volume of the solid by rotating about the x-axis.

Tags: calculus

Let R be the region is bounded by $x = 3y - y^{2}$ and $y = x.$

I found the upper and lower limits which are 0, 2, but I can't seem to go past this step. I need to use cylindrical shells.

Comment: Draw a picture. Take a thin strip at height $y$, rotate about the $x$-axis. The radius of the shell is $y$, and the "height" of the cylindrical shell is $(3-y^2)-y$. I imagine the rest will not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

The parabola is multi-valued on $x\in[0,2]$ which portion should be chosen?

\begin{align*}
  y_{\pm}&=\frac{3\pm \sqrt{9-4x}}{2} \\
  V_{+} &=\pi\int_{0}^{2} [(y_{+})^{2}-x^{2}] \, dx \\ &=
  \pi\left[
       -\frac{1}{32} (9-4x)^{2}-\frac{1}{4} (9-4x)^{3/2}
       -\frac{9}{16} (9-4x)-\frac{x^{3}}{3}
     \right]_{0}^{2} \\ &=
  \frac{65\pi}{6} \\ 
  V_{-} &= \pi\int_{0}^{2} [x^{2}-(y_{-})^{2}] \, dx \\ &=
  \pi\left[
       \frac{x^{3}}{3}+\frac{x^{2}}{2}-
       \frac{1}{4} (9-4x)^{3/2}+\frac{9}{8} (9-4x)
     \right]_{0}^{2} \\ &=
  \frac{13\pi}{6}
\end{align*}
[image]